# Defining variables within JavaScript Promise Declaration as opposed to outside

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm just trying to get my head around JavaScript Promises and I'm confused about something.

What is the difference between the following two functions?

```
function func_1()
{
     var myArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        arg_1 = (myArgs[1]) ? myArgs[1] : 1,
        arg_2 = (myArgs[2]) ? myArgs[2] : 2
        ;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var result = arg_1 + arg_2;
        resolve(result);
    });
}

function func_2()
{    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
    {
        var myArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            arg_1 = (myArgs[1]) ? myArgs[1] : 1,
            arg_2 = (myArgs[2]) ? myArgs[2] : 2
            ;

        var result = arg_1 + arg_2;
        resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function will work as you expect, because it accesses the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) of the `func_1()` call.

Your second function accesses the `arguments` of the anonymous callback function that you pass to the `Promise` constructor. Here, `myArgs == [resolve, reject]`.

Notice that for your task you should not use the `Promise` constructor with its callbacks at all, but the [`Promise.resolve` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
function func(_, arg1, arg2) {
    return Promise.resolve((arg1 || 1) + (arg2 || 2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes it much clearer. Points also for the elegant code compression.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, those two functions will result in essentially the same behavior, with the exception that in func_2, your arguments will refer to the arguments of the Promise callback instead of the args of the func_2 closure, which will certainly cause bugs in your code. The example, however, doesn't really utilize Promises in the way they are designed for.

The best way to understand how a promise works, is to use it to handle asynchronous behavior. So, if you change your example to the following:

```
function func_1()
{  
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.get('stuff.json')
        .success(function (result) {
            resolve(result);
        }).fail(function () {
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

In this example, the promise starts an asynchronous request using jQuerys get method. When the request either succeeds or fails it either calls resolve or reject. So the way you'd use func_1 in your code is something like the following:

```
func_1().done(function (result) {
    // do something with the result
});
```

FYI, this example is a little contrived, since $.get already returns a promise you can do essentially the same thing with.